# Entity Framework-Getting value from navigational property

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have 3 entities in my model. A->B->C, where A is the super parent and C is the child. I C is derived from B, and B is derived from A. I am loading C into a datagrid, and I need to be able to display values from B and A. Right now I can display values of B by saying:

```
 dgIA.ItemsSource = ctx.C.OfType<SOME_TYPE>().Include("B");
```

And in my xaml I say:

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="property 1" Binding="{Binding A.Name}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="property 2" Binding="{Binding B.Name}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="property 3" Binding="{Binding Frequency}"/>//a value in C
```

I need to be able to display A.Name, but if I try to include A by saying:

```
ctx.C.OfType<SOME_TYPE>().Include("B").Include("A");
```

I get the exception:

**A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'DB.SOME_TYPE' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'A'.**

I understand why it is doing this, as My entity C only has a navigational property to B, and B has a navigational property to A, but I want C to be able to get a value from A in  the way that I have shown. How would I do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try Include("B.A") instead.

Comment: This doesn't pull an exception, but it isn't pulling any data. So I don't know if that is for a different reason now.

Comment: Fixed it. had to say ZONE.GACC.Name in the xaml. Thank you!

Comment: Use include in this way:  ctx.C.OfType<SOME_TYPE>().Include(e => e.B).Include(e => e.B.A);

Comment: It actually works by only changing the xaml. See the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So by saying in my xaml:

```
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="property 1" Binding="{Binding B.A.Name}"/>
```

This accessed the nav property of B to access A.

And:

```
  dgIA.ItemsSource = ctx.A.OfType<SOME_TYPE>();
```

no includes or anything was needed. Apprently EF's 'Relationship Fix-Up' handles it, you just need dot accessors.